# Не срабатывает тег <ul> в Битрикс

Tags: html, битрикс

Здравствуйте! Столкнулась с проблемой - не получается создать маркированный список в Битрикс. В чем может быть проблема? Пишу как обычно, ничего нового:

```
<ul>
<li>текст</li>
<li>текст</li>
<li>текст</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего в стилях у вас прописано так отображать, само по себе так не будет. Проверьте в стилях сайта, стилях компонентов или как вариант присвойте спиской свой новый уникальный id и задайте стиль относительно этого id.

**Вариант 1:**

CSS:

```
#list {
 list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
<li>1
<li>2
<li>3
</ul>
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
<ul style="list-style-type: disc">
   <li>1
   <li>2
   <li>3
</ul>
```

Comment: именно id присвоить? Не класс?

Comment: @AllaAkbirova Можно и класс, просто он должен быть уникальный со своими свойствами, потому что судя по всему либо стиль сайта, либо какого-то компонента перебивает стандартный ul

Comment: спасибо, но все равно не срабатывает

Comment: @AllaAkbirova 2ой вариант пробовали? Пробовали менять значение list-style-type на, например какой нибудь из этих: circle | disc | square | armenian | decimal . Вообще никакой маркер не отображается?

Comment: вообще никакой. Максимум чего я добилась, что этим маркеры появились в неожиданном месте сайта

Comment: @AllaAkbirova Давайте продолжим дальнейшее обсуждение в чате http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46679/ul--

Comment: к сожалению не могу. Пишет, что моя репутация должна быть минимум 20, чтобы использовать эту возможность

Comment: @AllaAkbirova тогда поищите в каталоге вашего сайта все файлы и в них уже посмотрите, где то должно ul упоминаться. Также вам облегчить поиск должен исходный код страницы через браузер, просто правой кнопкой по элементу (списку) и должен быть пункт наподобие "исходный код", откроется форма и там должны быть видны свойства ul и в каком файле описаны. После приложите к вопросу и будем разбираться дальше:)

Comment: в main css прописано list-style: none, но насколько я понимаю, если я присваивают тегу <ul> класс или id, то он должен сработать на той конкретной странице, к которую я описываю. Какие же могут быть подводные камни?)

Comment: @AllaAkbirova вот, нашли. Потому что родительский элемент старше по приоритету. Значит можно попробовать не совсем красивым, но так должно работать, образом. Нужно добавить свойство !important для стиля. Сейчас изменю Вариант 1, попробуйте

Comment: таким образом тоже пробовала,но тогда маркеры списка возникают в неожиданном месте - в шапке сайта

Comment: Потому что скорее всего @AllaAkbirova переопределяете стиль для всех списков на странице. Проверьте точно ли подключается новый стиль в таблице (и да в примере выше ошибка задается id "list", а стиль применяется к классу "list", нужно через # задавать `#list{}`.)

Comment: @ArtResh согласен, моя ошибка, сейчас исправлю.

Comment: @ArtResh все элементы корректно реагируют на подключенный стиль, не затрагивая ни шапку, ни подвал, и только этот не поддается.

Comment: у вас отступы между маркерами и самими пунктами, поэтому вы видите их в "странных местах"

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко поясните пожалуйста, какие отступы?

Comment: Большое спасибо, помог 2 вариант.